# Product recommendation cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following simple graph -

[image: product graph]

I wish to build a simple recommendation system on the basis of the following example:

1. Consider that we have invoice 1 with an Article "Apple".
2. We also have invoice 2 which has "Apple" and "Oranges".
3. Customer of invoice 1 should be recommended "Oranges".

Basically, When a customer adds an item to an invoice, we need to recommend articles that were added to another invoice with at least one of its article in the current invoice. And the recommended article not in the current invoice.

Another way to say this -

When an article A exists in Invoice 1 AND Invoice 2 also contains article A, then list all other articles in Invoice 2 provided they do not exist in Invoice 1.

However, as a complete beginner I'm unable to figure out how to write the cypher query. Any help on how to write such a query?

Comment: you can take inspiration from a neo4j tutorial which does something very similar to your use case https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/guide-build-a-recommendation-engine/

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work to start with:

```
MATCH (i:Invoice)-[]-(a:Article)-[]-(:Invoice)-[]-(b:Article) 
WHERE i.invoiceNumber = 123
RETURN b;
```

What is does is - start from the invoice, then navigate through the articles connected to that invoice, onto other invoices (all other invoices that share this article). From there it collects all the articles connected to those invoices.
(this assumes that you are using unique `Article`nodes and connecting the invoices to them)

Comment: I believe this is not an answer but a clue, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for a given Customer (let say Customer1), give me other customers and recommended food based on any food that Customer1 ordered and common to other customers.

```
MATCH (c1:Customer {name: 'Customer1'})<-[:GENERATED_FOR]-(:Invoice)<-[:ITEMIZED_IN]-(:Article)-[:TYPE]->(f:FoodArticle)
WITH c1, collect(f) as food 
MATCH (c2:Customer)<-[:GENERATED_FOR]-(:Invoice)<-[:ITEMIZED_IN]-(:Article)-[:TYPE]->(f2:FoodArticle) 
   WHERE c1 <> c2 AND f2 in food
WITH c2, food, collect(f2) as food2
WITH c2, [fd IN food WHERE NOT fd IN food2] as recommendations 
   WHERE size(recommendations) > 0
RETURN c2.name, recommendations
```

> 1. First, get all food that customer1 has ordered
> 2. Next, find all customers that has at least one food contained in Customer1's food
> 3. List out customer2 and collect all food for this customer2
> 4. Create a list of recommended food based on those found in customer1 food list BUT NOT found in customer2 food list
> 5. Return customer2 name and recommended food but ensure that there is at least one food in Customer1 list that is not found in customer2 list (food2)